# Как получить всевозможные подходящие варианты остатков

Tags: python

Задача – выбрать несколько заданных чисел (1 ≤ несколько ≤ N) таким образом, чтобы сумма выбранных чисел была кратна N.
есть двумерный список в котором записаны остатки от деления на конкретное число n,
например:

```
n = 5
```

а массив исходных чисел

```
a = [1,2,3,4,1]
```

мой список остатков будет выглядеть так:

```
d = [ [], [1, 1], [2], [3], [4] ]
```

индекс первого элемента равен остатку от деления на пять, т.е( от 0 до 4)
а внутри списка уже сами числа, пришлось использовать двумерный список, чтоб избавиться от перезаписи чисел с одинаковыми остатками

нужно вывести несколько чисел которые будут кратны нашему n.
для этого я использую остатки, ведь если сумма остатков кратна n, то и сумма чисел будет кратна n.
вопрос в том как эффективно перебрать все эти числа (лимит в контесте 1 секунда и 64мб памяти). нужно перебрать все числа с остатками которые в сумме дают наше число n и вывести эту комбинацию в ответ(если комбинаций несколько вывести можно любую)
пытался использовать combinations, но скорее всего получу timelimit, т.к ограничение на n: (1 ≤ n ≤ 10000)
прикладываю свой код

```
n = int(input())
a = []
for x in range(n):
    a.append(int(input()))

d = [[] for x in range(n)]

for x in range(len(a)):
    d[a[x]%n].append(a[x])

print(d)
```

так я пытался перебрать все числа из этого списка, сумма остатков которых дает n

```
b = [x for x in range(1,n+1)]

c = [list(i) for x in range(1,n) for i in combinations(b,x) if len(i) > 1 and sum(i) == n]

for x in range(len(d)):
    for i in range(x,len(d)):
        for j in c:
            if (x == j[0] and i == j[1]) or (x == j[1] and i == j[0]):
                if len(d[x]) > 0 and len(d[i]) > 0:
                    print(len(j))
                    print(d[x][0],d[i][0],sep = "\n")
```

a = [1,2,3,4,1]
Ответом на задачу с примером массива a:

```
2  # кол-во чисел
2  # число 1
3  # число 2
```

Если будет найдено несколько комбинаций подходящих чисел, можно вывести любую.
Комбинация из одного числа не подходит (1 ≤ комбинация ≤ n)

Comment: Какую задачу вы решаете? Не что вы делаете а зачем вы это делаете? Добавьте в вопрос формулировку задачи.

Comment: Задача – выбрать несколько заданных чисел (1 ≤ несколько ≤ N) таким образом, чтобы сумма выбранных чисел была кратна N, т.е. равнялась N · k для некоторого целого k.